# Is restriction of scalars an exact functor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For the notion of restriction of scalars (aka Weil restriction) I have in mind, see [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_restriction).
My question then is

> Is the restriction of scalars an exact functor for ses of smooth linear algebraic $k$-groups, for some fixed field $k$?

Comment: What do you mean by an exact sequence of varieties?

Comment: @Slade I see your point now (I was being a bit confused). I've edited accordingly! Thanks

Comment: Could you include your definitions?  I don't want to trivialize the question, but all the definitions I'm finding for kernels and images of group varieties only involve the points and the group structure, not the algebraic structure.  Since restricting scalars has no effect on the points or the group structure, it's exact for trivial reasons.

Comment: Also—and this might not be important, but I thought I should point it out—restricting scalars from $K$ to $k\subset K$ isn't a functor from linear algebraic $K$-groups to linear algebraic $k$-groups, at least not without some restrictions, because we might lose finite type.  Finite extensions are probably okay, but it's not obvious to me that we'll still get a linear group.

Comment: Okay, it's at least a functor when $k\subset K$ is a finite extension—the dimension goes up, but an automorphism of a $K$-vector space is still an automorphism as a $k$-vector space.

Comment: @Slade Yes, I can take K/k to be a finite extension. So if I just consider a ses of group schemes, Weil restriction gives me back a ses of group schemes, right?  Do you know any good references to learn about Weil restriction? I know very little about it (as you might have guessed from my confusion), and I'd like to learn more.

Comment: Again, you should show me your definitions before I can give you a definitive answer.  If you take a short exact sequence of _groups_, then the same sequence is a short exact sequence of _groups_, and adding "over $K$" or "over $k$" to the mix doesn't matter.  But if your definitions allow for things like non-reduced points, I might worry about inseparable extensions or something.

Comment: And no, I don't know of references that discuss this specifically (besides the ones on the Wikipedia page).  It's a basic technique, and as such, it appears all over the place, either as an elementary triviality, or as some more advanced theorems about stacks.